# Default project missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, default-package

In my Output console, i cant seem to find default project.
[image: One Console from a youtube page, And mine]

Does anyone know how to get it back?

The picture with the arrow is from a youtube video, the black screen is mine.

**Edit:**

I noticed my location of the arrow is really stupid.

The text below is Default Project

Comment: You should open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio and not the Output window to see this option.

Comment: In general, you can find all the corresponding parts of vs in the view. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmI70.png

Comment: Yes, i believe YungDeiza gave also a similar answer, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to view in the toolbar
- Then go to other windows
- Then click on Package Manager Console